# Wordress Redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I had my wordpress website under a folder inside my domain root http://example.com/oldfolder/. Now I have changed the wordpress folder's name to http://example.com/newfolder/ and I need to create redirects for my posts which were shared on facebook because on Facebook they point to http://example.com/oldfolder. I need to create a redirect so that if a user click on the facebook post it redirects him from http://example.com/oldfolder/index.php/post-category/the-post-tile/ to http://example.com/newfolder/index.php/post-category/the-post-tile/

I have tried the following redirect rules:

1. Redirect 301 /oldfolder/ http://example.com/newfolder/
2. RewriteRule ^/oldfolder/^(.*) /newfolder/$1 [L,R=301]
3. RedirectMatch 301 /oldfolder/^(.*) /newfolder/$1

But none of the above worked. I installed the WP redirection plugin but it also didn't work.

Could some please tell me how properly set up the redirect rules?

Thank you!

Comment: check your .htaccess file, i think it has still the old name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^oldfolder/index\.php/(.*)/(.*)$ http://yoursite.com/newfolder/index.php/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it with number 2 - the condition checked against starts after the `/` in the URL so you need to leave that off the start like so:

`RewriteRule ^oldfolder/(.*)   /newfolder/$1 [L,R=301]`

Demo: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=4e06922b-9f70-5c5b-af8c-cf6544eb984d

**EDIT:** Oh yeah, and `^` only has special meaning at the start of a regex, where it anchors it to the start of a string, or to negate a character class so inside `[]` like so, for example: `[^az]`, which reads "match a character not 'a' or 'z'".

Comment: Doesn't there need to be a $ at the end of ^oldfoler/(.*) like this:

RewriteRule ^oldfolder/(.*)$   /newfolder/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: @Bananaapple, thanks for the suggestion. However when I try it, it gives me the error "The requested URL /oldfolder.php was not found on this server." Please also bear in mind that it is a wordpress!

Comment: @Brum, I tried your suggestion, it also didn't work.

Comment: @Brum - no need. `$` anchors the regex to the end of the string. `.*` matches everything (except newlines) so in the case of a URL rewrite the `$` is superfluous as `.*` will bring it to the end anyway. But a mute point since this apparently doesn't cut it for wordpress one way or the other :D